# How does Pym particle containment work?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In *Ant-Man*, we're introduced to Pym particles

> and a few knock-off versions of Pym particles

, which when they're exposed to matter, cause the matter to shrink in size.  Yet obviously they're stored in a manner that prevents this shrinkage from occurring.

> But we see them sprayed onto animals, dropped from a pipette, and used in weapons.

And in each of those uses, only the target object gets shrunk.  So how do the Pym particle storage and delivery systems avoid being shrunk?

Comment: This is a reimagining of an age-old problem. People have speculated for centuries about a universal solvent (something that dissolves anything it comes into contact with), and what you would store it in.

Comment: -1 Honestly, I am just going to downvote questions from now on that are totally and entirely absurd. Anybody with even an ounce of common sense will understand that some amount of suspension of disbelieve is necessary for superpowers. Asking about some random impossible consequence of a random impossibility that is necessary for the superpower is totally absurd and useless.

Comment: (Why btw does it say the question was modified by Community, but I can't see any edits or anything :S)

Comment: @DavidMulder Community will periodically bump old questions which haven't had much attention or answers, to give them a second chance at front page attention/answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two options:

1. The containers are made of something that cannot be shrunk. Similar to how acid can be safely stored in glass. Its passive and doesn't require any other external resources like a battery [Very likely]
2. An extremely powerful magnetic field is used to hold the particles in a vacuum away from the edges of the container. Similar to how [antimatter](http://singularityhub.com/2011/06/11/scientists-trap-antimatter-for-more-than-16-minutes-video/) is contained. This would require a fair amount of power [Less likely]

Comment: But, but, but... the (transparent) vials of Pym particles appear to be loaded into the suit as is, and when the suit shrinks, they shrink too.  That would seem to rule out #1.

Comment: Alright, magnetic giggery-pokery it is so

Comment: Perhaps it's more like explosives, where both explosive and detonator are required to actually trigger the (explosion, shrinkage).  Alas the detonator never makes it onto the mantel...

Comment: Maybe the glass containers already shrank once it touched the particle...

Comment: @MyCodeSucks That introduces the same problem that gowenfawr mentioned - the vials shrink along with the suit which uses them. They can't possibly be at their limit of shrinkability. And we know that there's no limit of shrinkability except that which is determined by an external regulator.

Comment: I favour the "detonator" explanation: The particle can *potentially* cause shrinkage, but only does so when stimulated in a particular fashion. Which could explain why the suit has a "regulator..." Kinda. Sorta. Maybe.